# INSERT statement executes, but doesn't create any new rows?

Tags: sql-server, triggers, insert

I've written a trigger for one of our company tables in SQL Server that executes on an UPDATE or an INSERT. When dealing with an INSERT, I need to insert two rows into a separate table. Every part of the trigger is working properly except the INSERT statement at the very end. It's not throwing any errors, the SQL Profiler says the INSERT executed, and it works fine when I copy and paste it into its own query in SQL Server and replace the local variables with constants. But the trigger isn't creating any new rows in the table it's supposed to be inserting into.

My code is below:

```
    USE [DLIDEMO3]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[EMAIL_ON_UPDATE]    Script Date: 7/13/2016 9:36:40 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[EMAIL_ON_UPDATE]
    ON  [dbo].[PART]
    AFTER INSERT, UPDATE

AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @old_part_id nvarchar(30); -- The value of the ID field from before the change (Used to determine if the part existed before the change).
DECLARE @old_description nvarchar(40); -- The value of the DESCRIPTION field before the change.
DECLARE @old_drawing_id nvarchar(30); -- The value of the DRAWING_ID field before the change. 
DECLARE @old_drawing_rev_no nvarchar(8); -- The value of the DRAWING_REV_NO field before the change.
DECLARE @old_cust_num nvarchar(80); -- The value of the USER_2 field before the change.

DECLARE @new_description nvarchar(40); -- The value of the DESCRIPTION field after the change.
DECLARE @new_drawing_id nvarchar(30); -- The value of the DRAWING_ID field after the change.
DECLARE @new_drawing_rev_no nvarchar(8); -- The value of the DRAWING_REV_NO field after the change.
DECLARE @new_cust_num nvarchar(80); -- The value of the USER_2 field after the change.

DECLARE @stock_um nvarchar(15); -- The value of the STOCK_UM field after the change.
DECLARE @part_id nvarchar(30); -- The value of the ID field.
DECLARE @product_code nvarchar(15); -- The value of the PRODUCT_CODE field.
DECLARE @status nchar(1); -- The value of the STATUS field.

SELECT
@old_part_id = ID,
@old_description = DESCRIPTION,
@old_drawing_id = DRAWING_ID,
@old_drawing_rev_no = DRAWING_REV_NO,
@old_cust_num = USER_2
FROM deleted;

SELECT
@part_id = ID,
@stock_um = STOCK_UM,
@product_code = PRODUCT_CODE,
@status = STATUS,
@new_description = DESCRIPTION,
@new_drawing_id = DRAWING_ID,
@new_drawing_rev_no = DRAWING_REV_NO,
@new_cust_num = USER_2
FROM inserted;

DECLARE @change_type nvarchar(10) -- Keeps track of what kind of email needs to be sent: UPDATED, INSERTED, or NONE.

SET @change_type =  N'NONE';

-- Determines if any of these fields have changed since before the statement executed, and if so, assigns 'UPDATED' to @change_type.
IF ISNULL(@old_description, 'ISNULL') <> ISNULL(@new_description, 'ISNULL')
    SET @change_type = N'UPDATED';
IF ISNULL(@old_drawing_id, 'ISNULL') <> ISNULL(@new_drawing_id, 'ISNULL')
    SET @change_type = N'UPDATED';
IF ISNULL(@old_drawing_rev_no, 'ISNULL') <> ISNULL(@new_drawing_rev_no, 'ISNULL')
    SET @change_type = N'UPDATED';
IF ISNULL(@old_cust_num, 'ISNULL') <> ISNULL(@new_cust_num, 'ISNULL')
    SET @change_type = N'UPDATED';

-- Determines if the part ID existed before the statement, and if not, assigns 'INSERTED' to @change_type.
IF ISNULL(@old_part_id, 'ISNULL') = 'ISNULL'
    SET @change_type = N'INSERTED';

-- Determines if the part is a raw material, and if not, assigns 'NONE' to @change_type.
IF NOT((@product_code = N'raw' OR @product_code = N'rawotc'))
    SET @change_type = N'NONE';

DECLARE @msg varchar(MAX); -- The HTML body of the email to be sent.
DECLARE @subject_line varchar(200); -- The subject line of the email.
DECLARE @title varchar(50); -- The title to be displayed at the top of the table in the email.
DECLARE @bg_color varchar(6); -- The background color of the email.
DECLARE @colspan varchar(1); -- The number of columns in the table in the email.

-- Uses the @change_type to determine @bg_color, resulting in different-colored emails for different kinds of statements.
SET @bg_color =
CASE @change_type
    WHEN 'UPDATED' THEN 'FEFFB5'
    WHEN 'INSERTED' THEN 'C5E7FF'
    ELSE 'FFFFFF'
END;

-- Uses the @change_type to determine @title.
SET @title =
CASE @change_type
    WHEN 'UPDATED' THEN 'PART UPDATED: '+@part_id
    WHEN 'INSERTED' THEN 'NEW PART CREATED: '+@part_id
    ELSE @change_type
END;

-- Uses the @change_type to determine @colspan, since an UPDATED email requires one more column than an INSERTED email does.
SET @colspan =
CASE @change_type
    WHEN 'UPDATED' THEN '6'
    WHEN 'INSERTED' THEN '5'
    ELSE '5'
END;

SET @subject_line = @title;

SET @msg = 
'<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <style type="text/css">
            body
                {
                margin-left: 10px;
                margin-top: 10px;
                margin-right: 10px;
                margin-bottom: 10px;
                text-align: center;
                }

        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div style="font-size: 20px; font-weight: strong; text-align: center;">PART '+@part_id+' '+@change_type+' ON '+CAST(GETDATE() AS varchar(30))+' BY '+SYSTEM_USER+'.<br>';
IF ISNULL(@status, '') = N'O' -- Adds a note stating that the part is obsolete, but only if the part is actually obsolete.
    SET @msg = @msg + '<br>***NOTE: THIS PART IS OBSOLETE.***<br>';
SET @msg = @msg +
        '</div>
        <table width="100%" border="2" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5" bgcolor="#'+@bg_color+'">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="'+@colspan+'" align="center" valign="middle" style="font-family: Consolas, ''Andale Mono'', ''Lucida Console'', ''Lucida Sans Typewriter'', Monaco, ''Courier New'', monospace; font-weight: bold; font-size: 36px;"><p><!--<img src="/Images/DESLABLGtag3d.png" width="52" height="53" alt=""/>--><span style="font-size: 24px">'+@title+'</span></p></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>';

IF @change_type = 'UPDATED' -- Adds a column on the left for the 'OLD' and 'NEW' row titles.
    SET @msg = @msg + '<td width="10%"></td>';

SET @msg = @msg +                   
                    '<td width="30%" height="40" align="middle" valign="middle" style="font-weight: bold;">DESCRIPTION</td>
                    <td width="15%" height="40" align="middle" valign="middle" style="font-weight: bold;">UoM</td>
                    <td width="15%" height="40" align="middle" valign="middle" style="font-weight: bold;">CUST #</td>
                    <td width="15%" height="40" align="middle" valign="middle" style="font-weight: bold;">DRAWING</td>
                    <td width="15%" height="40" align="middle" valign="middle" style="font-weight: bold;">DRAWING REV #</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>';

IF @change_type = 'UPDATED'
    SET @msg = @msg + '<td width="10%" height="40" align="middle" valign="middle" style="font-weight: bold;">NEW</td>';

SET @msg = @msg +
                    '<td width="30%" height="40" align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor="#E5E5E5" style="font-size: 16px; font-family: Consolas, ''Andale Mono'', ''Lucida Console'', ''Lucida Sans Typewriter'', Monaco, ''Courier New'', monospace;">'+ISNULL(@new_description,'')+'</td>
                    <td width="15%" height="40" align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor="#E5E5E5" style="font-size: 16px; font-family: Consolas, ''Andale Mono'', ''Lucida Console'', ''Lucida Sans Typewriter'', Monaco, ''Courier New'', monospace;">'+ISNULL(@stock_um,'')+'</td>
                    <td width="15%" height="40" align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor="#E5E5E5" style="font-size: 16px; font-family: Consolas, ''Andale Mono'', ''Lucida Console'', ''Lucida Sans Typewriter'', Monaco, ''Courier New'', monospace;">'+ISNULL(@new_cust_num,'')+'</td>
                    <td width="15%" height="40" align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor="#E5E5E5" style="font-size: 16px; font-family: Consolas, ''Andale Mono'', ''Lucida Console'', ''Lucida Sans Typewriter'', Monaco, ''Courier New'', monospace;">'+ISNULL(@new_drawing_id,'')+'</td>
                    <td width="15%" height="40" align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor="#E5E5E5" style="font-size: 16px; font-family: Consolas, ''Andale Mono'', ''Lucida Console'', ''Lucida Sans Typewriter'', Monaco, ''Courier New'', monospace;">'+ISNULL(@new_drawing_rev_no,'')+'</td>
                </tr>';
IF @change_type = 'UPDATED'
    SET @msg = @msg +
                '<tr>
                    <td width="10%" height="40" align="middle" valign="middle" style="font-weight: bold;">OLD</td>
                    <td width="30%" height="40" align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor="#E5E5E5" style="font-size: 16px; font-family: Consolas, ''Andale Mono'', ''Lucida Console'', ''Lucida Sans Typewriter'', Monaco, ''Courier New'', monospace;">'+ISNULL(@old_description,'')+'</td>
                    <td width="15%" height="40" align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor="#E5E5E5" style="font-size: 16px; font-family: Consolas, ''Andale Mono'', ''Lucida Console'', ''Lucida Sans Typewriter'', Monaco, ''Courier New'', monospace;">'+ISNULL(@stock_um,'')+'</td>
                    <td width="15%" height="40" align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor="#E5E5E5" style="font-size: 16px; font-family: Consolas, ''Andale Mono'', ''Lucida Console'', ''Lucida Sans Typewriter'', Monaco, ''Courier New'', monospace;">'+ISNULL(@old_cust_num,'')+'</td>
                    <td width="15%" height="40" align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor="#E5E5E5" style="font-size: 16px; font-family: Consolas, ''Andale Mono'', ''Lucida Console'', ''Lucida Sans Typewriter'', Monaco, ''Courier New'', monospace;">'+ISNULL(@old_drawing_id,'')+'</td>
                    <td width="15%" height="40" align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor="#E5E5E5" style="font-size: 16px; font-family: Consolas, ''Andale Mono'', ''Lucida Console'', ''Lucida Sans Typewriter'', Monaco, ''Courier New'', monospace;">'+ISNULL(@old_drawing_rev_no,'')+'</td>
                </tr>';

SET @msg = @msg +       
            '</tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>';

-- Sends an email only if @change_type is 'INSERTED' or 'UPDATED'.
IF @change_type <> 'NONE'
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @recipients = 'example@email.com', @body = @msg, @body_format = 'HTML',  @subject = @subject_line, @blind_copy_recipients = 'generic@email.com', @profile_name = 'SQLProfile';

IF @change_type = 'INSERTED'
    INSERT INTO [DLIDEMO3].[dbo].[USER_DEF_FIELDS]
    (PROGRAM_ID, ID, DOCUMENT_ID, DATE_VAL, STRING_VAL)
    VALUES 
        (N'VMPRTMNT', N'UDF-0000023', @part_id, GETDATE(), NULL),
        (N'VMPRTMNT', N'UDF-0000024', @part_id, NULL, N'NEW PART CREATED BY '+SYSTEM_USER);
END
```

What am I doing wrong? How could the INSERT be executing (according to SQL Profiler) without producing an error, but still not be doing anything?

Comment: SQL Profiler says the INSERT executed? Are you sure it is informing an insertion in `[DLIDEMO3].[dbo].[USER_DEF_FIELDS]`. probably you would have one of the problems.
1. Profiler is telling about some insertion which is occuring in procedure `msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @recipients` or if profiler is really telling insertion in `DLIDEMO3].[dbo].[USER_DEF_FIELDS]` then it should not be telling lie, you might be making mistake in checking the insertion (might be looking different table or database) Be sure your look is accurate

Comment: Your trigger has a MAJOR design flaw. You seem to assume there will only ever be 1 row inserted or updated. This is not the case. You should make this set based and get rid of those scalar variables. I would also suggest you don't send emails directly from your trigger. Instead create a staging table and a scheduled task to gather the data and send emails.

Comment: @Sami, This is what the Profiler says executed:
`INSERT INTO [DLIDEMO3].[dbo].[USER_DEF_FIELDS]
  (PROGRAM_ID, ID, DOCUMENT_ID, DATE_VAL, STRING_VAL)
  VALUES 
   (N'VMPRTMNT', N'UDF-0000023', @part_id, GETDATE(), NULL),
   (N'VMPRTMNT', N'UDF-0000024', @part_id, NULL, N'NEW PART CREATED BY '+SYSTEM_USER);`


I've double-checked the table I'm looking in, it's the same one.

Comment: @Sean, I thought of that before designing the trigger, but this table is only ever manipulated through a front-end application that only allows one change at a time.

Comment: That is how it works today...what happens when some data is messed up and you need to update 10 rows? It can and will happen at some point. And if it is important that the email is sent for each change it will fail at that point. Most of the time it is far less code and easier to maintain when it is set based anyway. :)

Comment: @Sean, that's a separate issue. At the moment I just need to know how to get the INSERT to work.

Comment: On the contrary, why bother "fixing" code that you need to replace? Write it set based now including your insert and you won't need to bother looking at this later.

Comment: Why negative vote? Why close vote? Would you please guidethe the OP, what else should have been done..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of some tech support, I managed to figure out a working solution (though not one as immediate or elegant as I had hoped).

It turns out that the batch of statements that activated this trigger contained an `UPDATE` statement that was undoing the changes made by the trigger's `INSERT` statement, so I decided to use a staging table and a scheduled job to ensure some time separation between statements.

I created a new table:

```
USE [DLIDEMO3]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DLI_STAGING_RAWS](
    [PROGRAM_ID] [nvarchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [ID] [nvarchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [DOCUMENT_ID] [nvarchar](128) NULL,
    [DATE_VAL] [datetime] NULL,
    [STRING_VAL] [nvarchar](128) NULL,
    [CREATE_DATETIME] [datetime] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

I changed the `INSERT` statement in my trigger to:

```
INSERT INTO [DLIDEMO3].[dbo].[DLI_STAGING_RAWS]
        (PROGRAM_ID, ID, DOCUMENT_ID, DATE_VAL, STRING_VAL, CREATE_DATETIME)
        VALUES 
            (N'VMPRTMNT', N'UDF-0000023', @part_id, GETDATE(), NULL, GETDATE()),
            (N'VMPRTMNT', N'UDF-0000024', @part_id, NULL, N'NEW PART CREATED BY '+SYSTEM_USER, GETDATE());
```

And I created a scheduled job to execute once an hour, following these commands:

```
WHILE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [DLIDEMO3].[dbo].[DLI_STAGING_RAWS])
BEGIN
    DECLARE
    @program_id nvarchar(30),
    @id nvarchar(30),
    @document_id nvarchar(128),
    @date_val datetime,
    @string_val nvarchar(250),
    @create_datetime datetime;

    SELECT TOP 1
    @program_id = PROGRAM_ID,
    @id = ID,
    @document_id = DOCUMENT_ID,
    @date_val = DATE_VAL,
    @string_val = STRING_VAL,
    @create_datetime = CREATE_DATETIME
    FROM [DLIDEMO3].[dbo].[DLI_STAGING_RAWS]
    ORDER BY ID ASC;

    IF DATEDIFF(mi, @create_datetime, GETDATE()) >= 15
    BEGIN

        INSERT INTO [DLIDEMO3].[dbo].[USER_DEF_FIELDS]
        (PROGRAM_ID, ID, DOCUMENT_ID, DATE_VAL, STRING_VAL)
        VALUES
        (@program_id, @id, @document_id, @date_val, @string_val);

        DELETE FROM [DLIDEMO3].[dbo].[DLI_STAGING_RAWS]
        WHERE PROGRAM_ID = @program_id AND ID = @id AND DOCUMENT_ID = @document_id;
    END;
END;
```

(The `DATEDIFF` condition ensures that someone entering data right at the hour mark doesn't encounter the exact same problem I was having.)

This solution does essentially what I was trying to do with my previous `INSERT` statement, albeit staggered by an hour (which doesn't particularly matter in this case).

Thanks for all the constructive input. :)